# MSAL v3 Angular 16 samples apps give Error: Can't resolve '@azure/msal-angular'

Tags: angular, typescript, azure, azure-ad-msal

I'm trying to get the MSAL 3 Angular tutorial working on my Mac OS but I'm getting the following error when doing a `npm start` for the sample app:

```
Error: Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '@azure/msal-angular'
```

and

```
Error: Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '@azure/msal-browser'
```

This doesn't surprise me as in the sample app's `node_modules` directory the '**@azure/msal-angular**' and '**@azure/msal-browser**' node_modules folder do not exist.

The source is being cloned from:

https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-js/tree/dev

I initially tried to just do a `npm install` from the sample '**angular16-sample-app**' but the '**@azure/msal-angular**' node_modules sub-folder didn't install.

I did a fresh clone from git, and tried `npm install` from the root directory (the whole repo is quite large with multiple workspaces ... running from root does in fact build the sample app's node_modules sub-directory but without the '**@azure/msal-angular**' and '**@azure/msal-browser**' modules similarly to if the install was done in the sample app directory.

There are no errors on the `npm install` processes, and I've previously gotten the MSAL v2 tutorials working no trouble.

What am I missing? Is there some linking step I'm missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fixed it!

In the tsconfig.json there was the following paths:

```
"paths": {
  "@angular/*": [
    "./node_modules/@angular/*"
  ],
  "@azure/msal-angular": [
    "../../../node_modules/@azure/msal-angular/dist"
  ]
},
```

Apart from there not being any `@azure/msal-browser` path, removing these paths removes the link to the root git repo links and installs the @azure/msal-* libraries in the project's **node_modules**' directory.