# Error comes when Installing MSAL to Angular App

Tags: node.js, angular, typescript, azure, azure-ad-msal

Currently, I'm working on integrating Microsoft Authentication to Angular App. So, I'm following official documentation from Microsoft. [Link to documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/enable-authentication-angular-spa-app).

According to that, I installed **@azure/msal-angular** and **@azure/msal-browser.** Then I imported those to src/app/app.module.ts like this.

- Here is the code of **app.module.ts**

```
// For Microsoft Authentication
import {
  IPublicClientApplication,
  PublicClientApplication,
  BrowserCacheLocation,
  LogLevel,
  InteractionType,
} from '@azure/msal-browser';
import {
  MSAL_INSTANCE,
  MSAL_INTERCEPTOR_CONFIG,
  MsalInterceptorConfiguration,
  MSAL_GUARD_CONFIG,
  MsalGuardConfiguration,
  MsalBroadcastService,
  MsalService,
  MsalGuard,
  MsalRedirectComponent,
  MsalModule,
  MsalInterceptor,
} from '@azure/msal-angular';
```

Next I will attach code of package.json

```
{
  "name": "material",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "license": "MIT",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build --prod",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e",
    "bundle:report": "source-map-explorer dist/**/*.js"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "-": "0.0.1",
    "@angular-devkit/core": "9.0.2",
    "@angular/animations": "^9.1.4",
    "@angular/cdk": "^8.2.3",
    "@angular/cli": "^9.1.7",
    "@angular/common": "^9.0.1",
    "@angular/compiler": "9.0.1",
    "@angular/core": "^9.0.1",
    "@angular/flex-layout": "^9.0.0-beta.29",
    "@angular/forms": "9.0.1",
    "@angular/http": "^7.2.16",
    "@angular/material": "^8.2.3",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "9.0.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "9.0.1",
    "@angular/router": "9.0.1",

    "@azure/msal-angular": "^3.0.13",
    "@azure/msal-browser": "^3.10.0",
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^0.901.7",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "9.0.1",
    "@angular/language-service": "9.0.1",
    "@types/chartist": "^0.9.47",
    "@types/jasmine": "~3.3.8",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "^2.0.8",
    "@types/jquery": "^3.3.32",
    "@types/node": "^12.11.1",
    "protractor": "^7.0.0",
    "ts-node": "~3.2.0",
    "tslint": "~5.7.0",
    "typescript": "3.7.5"
  }
}
```

Error is :

```
ERROR in node_modules/@azure/msal-common/dist/index.d.ts:13:10 - error TS1005: 'from' expected.

13 export * as AuthToken from "./account/AuthToken";
            ~~
node_modules/@azure/msal-common/dist/index.d.ts:13:13 - error TS1005: ';' expected.

13 export * as AuthToken from "./account/AuthToken";
               ~~~~~~~~~
node_modules/@azure/msal-common/dist/index.d.ts:13:23 - error TS1005: ';' expected.

13 export * as AuthToken from "./account/AuthToken";
                         ~~~~
node_modules/@azure/msal-common/dist/index.d.ts:13:28 - error TS1005: ';' expected.

13 export * as AuthToken from "./account/AuthToken";
                              ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
node_modules/@azure/msal-common/dist/index.d.ts:20:10 - error TS1005: 'from' expected.

20 export * as AuthorityFactory from "./authority/AuthorityFactory";
            ~~
node_modules/@azure/msal-common/dist/index.d.ts:20:13 - error TS1005: ';' expected.

20 export * as AuthorityFactory from "./authority/AuthorityFactory";
               ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
node_modules/@azure/msal-common/dist/index.d.ts:20:30 - error TS1005: ';' expected.

20 export * as AuthorityFactory from "./authority/AuthorityFactory";
                                ~~~~
node_modules/@azure/msal-common/dist/index.d.ts:20:35 - error TS1005: ';' expected.

20 export * as AuthorityFactory from "./authority/AuthorityFactory";
                                     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
node_modules/@azure/msal-common/dist/index.d.ts:29:10 - error TS1005: 'from' expected.

29 export * as CacheHelpers from "./cache/utils/CacheHelpers";
            ~~
node_modules/@azure/msal-common/dist/index.d.ts:29:13 - error TS1005: ';' expected.

29 export * as CacheHelpers from "./cache/utils/CacheHelpers";
               ~~~~~~~~~~~~
node_modules/@azure/msal-common/dist/index.d.ts:29:26 - error TS1005: ';' expected.

29 export * as CacheHelpers from "./cache/utils/CacheHelpers";
                            ~~~~
node_modules/@azure/msal-common/dist/index.d.ts:29:31 - error TS1005: ';' expected.

29 export * as CacheHelpers from "./cache/utils/CacheHelpers";
                                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
node_modules/@azure/msal-common/dist/index.d.ts:84:10 - error TS1005: 'from' expected.

84 export * as AADServerParamKeys from "./constants/AADServerParamKeys";
            ~~
node_modules/@azure/msal-common/dist/index.d.ts:84:13 - error TS1005: ';' expected.

84 export * as AADServerParamKeys from "./constants/AADServerParamKeys";
               ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
node_modules/@azure/msal-common/dist/index.d.ts:84:32 - error TS1005: ';' expected.

84 export * as AADServerParamKeys from "./constants/AADServerParamKeys";
                                  ~~~~
node_modules/@azure/msal-common/dist/index.d.ts:84:37 - error TS1005: ';' expected.

84 export * as AADServerParamKeys from "./constants/AADServerParamKeys";
                                       ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
node_modules/@azure/msal-common/dist/index.d.ts:88:10 - error TS1005: 'from' expected.

88 export * as TimeUtils from "./utils/TimeUtils";
            ~~
node_modules/@azure/msal-common/dist/index.d.ts:88:13 - error TS1005: ';' expected.

88 export * as TimeUtils from "./utils/TimeUtils";
               ~~~~~~~~~
node_modules/@azure/msal-common/dist/index.d.ts:88:23 - error TS1005: ';' expected.

88 export * as TimeUtils from "./utils/TimeUtils";
                         ~~~~
node_modules/@azure/msal-common/dist/index.d.ts:88:28 - error TS1005: ';' expected.

88 export * as TimeUtils from "./utils/TimeUtils";
                              ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
node_modules/@azure/msal-common/dist/index.d.ts:89:10 - error TS1005: 'from' expected.

89 export * as UrlUtils from "./utils/UrlUtils";
            ~~
node_modules/@azure/msal-common/dist/index.d.ts:89:13 - error TS1005: ';' expected.

89 export * as UrlUtils from "./utils/UrlUtils";
               ~~~~~~~~
node_modules/@azure/msal-common/dist/index.d.ts:89:22 - error TS1005: ';' expected.

89 export * as UrlUtils from "./utils/UrlUtils";
                        ~~~~
node_modules/@azure/msal-common/dist/index.d.ts:89:27 - error TS1005: ';' expected.

89 export * as UrlUtils from "./utils/UrlUtils";
                             ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

** Angular Live Development Server is listening on localhost:4200, open your browser on http://localhost:4200/ **
```

I have removed some unnecessary codes from this to make these codes more clear.

I tried [this solution in Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76973087/msal-v3-angular-16-samples-apps-give-error-cant-resolve-azure-msal-angular). But could not fix it. I need to clarify this error and need to know how to fix or avoid this.  Thank you :)

Comment: Can I know your node version and typescript package version?

Comment: I have this **"typescript": "~5.4.2"** version, have installed the both **@azure/msal-angular and @azure/msal-browser** and imported those to **app.module.ts** code.

Comment: * Node Version : v14.15.0 in PC
* TypeScript Version : 3.7.5 in Project

Comment: Can you update your node version to 18?

Comment: Follow this [link](https://nodejs.org/en/download) to install node 18.

Comment: Use this command to update the **npm install @azure/msal-angular@latest @azure/msal-browser@latest** packages.

Comment: Previously, I tried to run this project with a new NodeJS version. But it does not work with it. Anyway, let me try with it

Comment: Install the node 18 version and check it once. Can you send the screenshot of the error you are getting in **app.module.ts** code?

Comment: Have you fixed the issue?

Comment: Not yet. I tried the above solutions. But couldn’t

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/257224/discussion-between-dasari-kamali-and-lakindu-widuranga-alvis).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed the issue. The problem is **we can not use MSAL Version 03 with Angular 9**. So I installed **MSAL packages - version 2** and now it's working.

Answer (score 0):

I followed this [MS DOC](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/enable-authentication-angular-spa-app), changed the **app-routing.module.ts** and **auth-config.ts** codes as given below. I successfully logged in with the Azure B2C tenant.

Use the commands below to create the Angular project and install the msal and material packages.

```
ng new msal-angular --routing=true --style=css --strict=false --no-standalone

npm install @azure/msal-browser @azure/msal-angular

npm install @angular/material @angular/cdk
```

**Note:** The ***styles.css*** code from the above MS DOC gives errors. As it is optional, I didn't use it in my Angular project.

**Code :**

***src/app/app-routing.module.ts :***

```js
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';
import { MsalGuard } from '@azure/msal-angular';
import { HomeComponent } from './home/home.component';
import { ProfileComponent } from './profile/profile.component';
import { WebapiComponent } from './webapi/webapi.component';

const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: 'profile',
    component: ProfileComponent,
    canActivate: [MsalGuard]
  },
  {
    path: 'webapi',
    component: WebapiComponent,
    canActivate: [MsalGuard]
  },
  {
    path: '',
    component: HomeComponent
  }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes, {
    initialNavigation: 'enabledNonBlocking' 
  })],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

***src/app/auth-config.ts :***

```js
import { LogLevel, Configuration, BrowserCacheLocation } from '@azure/msal-browser';

const isBrowser = typeof window !== 'undefined';
const isIE = isBrowser && /(MSIE|Trident\/|Edge\/)/i.test(window.navigator.userAgent);

const b2cPolicies = {
    names: {
        signUpSignIn: "<signUpSignIn_policy_name>",
        editProfile: "<editProfile_policy_name>"
    },
    authorities: {
        signUpSignIn: {
            authority: "https://<tenant_name>.b2clogin.com/<tenant_name>.onmicrosoft.com/<signUpSignIn_policy_name>",
        },
        editProfile: {
            authority: "https://<tenant_name>.b2clogin.com/<tenant_name>.onmicrosoft.com/<editProfile_policy_name>"
        }
    },
    authorityDomain: "<tenant_name>.b2clogin.com"
};

const msalConfig: Configuration = {
    auth: {
        clientId: '<client_ID>',
        authority: isBrowser ? b2cPolicies.authorities.signUpSignIn.authority : '',
        knownAuthorities: isBrowser ? [b2cPolicies.authorityDomain] : [],
        redirectUri: isBrowser ? '/' : '',
    },
    cache: {
        cacheLocation: isBrowser ? BrowserCacheLocation.LocalStorage : null,
        storeAuthStateInCookie: isBrowser && isIE,
    },
    system: {
        loggerOptions: {
            loggerCallback: (logLevel, message, containsPii) => {
                console.log(message);
            },
            logLevel: LogLevel.Verbose,
            piiLoggingEnabled: false
        }
    }
};

const protectedResources = {
    todoListApi: {
        endpoint: "http://localhost:5000/api/todolist",
        scopes: ["https://<tenant_name>.onmicrosoft.com/api/tasks.read"],
    },
};
const loginRequest = {
    scopes: []
};
export { msalConfig, protectedResources, loginRequest };
```

***package.json :***

```json
{
  "name": "msal-angular",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "watch": "ng build --watch --configuration development",
    "test": "ng test",
    "serve:ssr:msal-angular": "node dist/msal-angular/server/server.mjs"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^17.3.0",
    "@angular/cdk": "^17.3.1",
    "@angular/common": "^17.3.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "^17.3.0",
    "@angular/core": "^17.3.0",
    "@angular/forms": "^17.3.0",
    "@angular/material": "^17.3.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^17.3.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^17.3.0",
    "@angular/platform-server": "^17.3.0",
    "@angular/router": "^17.3.0",
    "@angular/ssr": "^17.3.0",
    "@azure/msal-angular": "^3.0.13",
    "@azure/msal-browser": "^3.10.0",
    "express": "^4.18.2",
    "rxjs": "~7.8.0",
    "tslib": "^2.3.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.14.3"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^17.3.0",
    "@angular/cli": "^17.3.0",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^17.3.0",
    "@types/express": "^4.17.17",
    "@types/jasmine": "~5.1.0",
    "@types/node": "^18.18.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~5.1.0",
    "karma": "~6.4.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.2.0",
    "karma-coverage": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-jasmine": "~5.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "~2.1.0",
    "typescript": "~5.4.2"
  }
}
```

I added the Angular output **URL** in the B2C app **Authentication** as below.

```
http://localhost:4200/
```

[image]

I enabled the scope for the B2C tenant as below.

[image]

I granted **openid**, **offline_access**, and the (scope) **tasks.read** in B2C app **API permissions** as below.

[image]

**Output :**

The following Angular project ran successfully, as shown below:

[image]
[image]

**Browser output :**

I received the output below in the browser with the Angular output [URL](http://localhost:4200/). Then, I clicked on the **Login** button, as shown below:

[image]

I entered my account details for login and clicked on the **Sign in** button, as shown below:

[image]

After successfully logging in, I clicked on **Profile**, as shown below:

[image]

I viewed my profile details and clicked on **Web API**, as shown below:

[image]
[image]

I saw the following in the **Web API** and clicked on the **Logout** button to log out, as shown below.

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much. I'll try with this and let you know :)

Comment: Hi, Fixed the issue. The problem is we can not use MSAL Version 03 with Angular 9. So installed version 2 and now it's working.